# ArrayCollection not refreshed within loop

Tags: loops, combobox, flex4, arraycollection

I have a for loop and within the loop I am calling a remote object method that returns an `ArrayCollection`. At each iteration of the loop the content of the `ArrayCollection` changes and I am setting the `dataProvider` of a `ComboBox` to that `ArrayCollection` in each iteration.

However, only my last `ComboBox` is being binded to the latest content of the `ArrayCollection`.

The `remote_obj.getYN` is the function that takes as parameter the value from the loop and as such as I mentioned above in each iteration the content of the arrayCollection changes due to this function being called.

Below is my code snippet:

```
public function myFunc():void{

    for (roller = 0; roller < customizedFields_array.length; roller++) { 
        var newCol:FlexDataGridColumn = new FlexDataGridColumn();
        remote_obj.getYN(customizedFields_array.getItemAt(roller).FLD);
        newCol.filterComboBoxDataProvider = _YN; 
        newCol.filterComboBoxLabelField =customizedFields_array.getItemAt(roller).FLD; 
        newCol.filterComboBoxDataField =customizedFields_array.getItemAt(roller).FLD; 
        }
        cols.push(newCol);
    } 
        myDataGrid.columns = cols;
}
```

This is the getYN result function in Flex.

```
public function getYN_result(event:ResultEvent):void{
    _YN = event.result as ArrayCollection;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to go around this issue?
Many thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
customizedFields_array.refresh();  // refresh the array collection
myDataGrid.invalidateDisplayList();// refresh the datagrid
```

Comment: The customizedFields_array is just returing a lsit in which I am loop. The array of concern that needs to be updated in each iteration is the _YN arrayCollection. So u mean after setting newCol.filterComboBoxDataProvider = _YN, I need to refresh() the array?

Comment: try to refresh it... when I had problem with autorefresh the array.refresh() always worked...

Comment: I tried it..but in vain..it does not work. Any other help please?